# Angular.JS Global Variables and Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning Angular.JS for new web app projects at work, as an alternative to ASP.NET for smaller apps. I've been doing great, but I ran into a problem today and it's been wrecking my brain all day.

I have an App.JS file, which requires my app-core.JS file, which in turn--requires my main-controller.JS file. My work within the controller has been a pretty good learning experience. I came across where when I change my views, my variables would reset within the controller. So I read that I should be using a service to store global variables. So I created a service following a tutorial here:

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/

I inject the service into my controller and it seems to be working--however it's not working correctly. Inside of my service, I have a variable called RUNTIME, and a function called this.IncrementRunTime, which will return RUNTIME + 1. Inside of my controller, I have a variable called $scope.Runtime = service.IncrementRuntime(). Then I do a console.log and using Chrome's debugger, I can see the value of the runtime.

The problem is, the log shows that I am incrementing the runtime by a value of 2, instead of 1 each time. Literally--the log will show--every one second--1,3,5,7----instead of 1,2,3,4,5, etc. I cannot figure out why this is happening. Any ideas or thoughts about what I may be doing wrong here? Thanks!

UPDATE: Here is a link to my current project. I can't figure this out. If someone can download this project and help me out I'd appreciate it. I am so fed up with this. I have literally copy pasted the code below into my own project and it does the same thing. I then started a new project using that code below--and it worked, but then it stopped loading my view but the increment worked. I ran a compare against my code and the code below---100% match. I only need to prove that I can carry data and information and have it persist across view changes. Otherwise, I'm going to stick to ASP.NET projects so I can use Session Variables.  Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BysoWvPv5Aj5ZDZUZjN4S3ZPdk0/view?usp=sharing

UPDATE: Ok, so I made a discovery. It doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me why, but it's something as a web developer I should have checked sooner. The code runs and increments correctly (1 call per second) if I use Chrome, Edge, or IE; however the views will not load. If I use Firefox (my main development browser)--the views will load correctly, but the Interval will increment by 2 instead of 1. This makes very little sense to me. I use Chrome as my main personal browser and it saves all of my cookies, logins, etc. So i use Firefox as my development browser and it clears my cookies and form data every time I open a new window--so when Im testing apps that require authentication, i dont have to worry about Chrome keeping me logged in across testing sessions.

Comment: Your code works fine in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PCxfcDE84UxWiHnLOJXx?p=preview)

Comment: Seems like the issue is higher up in your code than just this bit. As @charlietfl noted, this looks fine. Check that your interval isn't being wrapped in another 1-second interval itself.

Comment: Hey guys, @charlietfl I added some new info if you guys are still willing to help!

Comment: nobody will download a zip file to sift through it...post the code here or make a plunker with it

Comment: I've already done that. It didn't help. My code I posted was the same as shown in the plunker below. I appreciate the thought, but the only way I can get this solved is by using my specific code. I've tried the plunker variations as listed below already and I can't replicate it. Its ok if you don't want to look at it. I was just asking. Otherwise I'll just stick to ASP, but if someone WOULD look at it. I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code on this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/O1zhkqhc0kKPe86PEsYR?p=preview

```
angular.module('global-service', [])
.service('service', function () {

    var running = 0;

    this.IncrementRunTime = function () {
        running = running + 1;

        return running;
    }

})
.controller('ctrl', function ($interval, $scope, service) {
  $scope.OnUpdate = function () {

      // Increments RUNTIME
      $scope.RUNTIME = service.IncrementRunTime();

      // Debug Info to console
      console.log("Runtime: " + $scope.RUNTIME);
  }

  $interval(function () { $scope.OnUpdate(); }, 1000);
});
```

Everything looks fine. Have you maybe nested 2 $interval calls ?

Comment: I will take a look at my code tonight and let you know how it goes...thanks for taking a look guys!

Comment: So my code looks exactly the same as this--EXCEPT I have all of my modules in different files and not in my main App.js.--and it still does the same thing. I have checked and double checked and I can't find anywhere I am calling $interval twice. I set a breakpoint in Chrome debugger and it literally shows my OnUpdate getting called twice per second and I can't figure out why.

Comment: I added a link to download my project in my original post. If someone can take a look and help me out I'd really appreciate it. I am doing the exact same thing. I did notice a spelling mistake on my function name in the code I uploaded, but I know thats not the issue.That was just the result of a copy/paste of some code when I was throwing this project together to upload. Function name casing got left off.

Comment: Also, sorry, I just realized I forgot to add my <script src> to my service.js file back to the index.html to the version I uploaded above. I took it out when I was testing having the service in the same file as the controller, but it didn't make a difference.